# Is it possible to obtain the fingerprint or face auth from the phone with flutter

Tags: flutter, encryption, sha256

I am looking into [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) library. What I understand is that you can use biometric auth locally only (you get a true or false for a match). What I need is to be able to get the auth information that is stored on the phone, generate a public and private key from that, and send the public key to the server.

Can this be done in Flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot get the biometric information itself. You can only ask the system to authenticate using biometrics.

Do read [Protecting keys with the Secure Enclave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/protecting_keys_with_the_secure_enclave), which may provide services that match your needs. You can use the Security Framework to create a biometric-protected public-private keypair. You just can't have access to the biometric data or the the private key directly (Secure Enclave will handle it for you).

Comment: Is this that cannot be done what is called biometric tokenization?

Comment: Correct. You cannot get access to the internal data structures (which generally are some kind of hash), and even more-so the raw data.